# Filtering NAs values in a data.frame

Tags: r, na

I wanted to filter all data having Age as "NA". So I used `train[train$Age != "NA",]` it always returns full data frame.

```
[1] 891
> nrow(train)
[1] 891
> nrow(train[train$Age == "NA",])
[1] 177
> nrow(train[train$Age != "NA",])
[1] 891
```

I am learning R and I got struck in a point. I know its so basic, but I'm not able to figure it out myself or with google.

Data set sample

```
     PassengerId Survived Pclass                                                Name    Sex Age SibSp Parch           Ticket
1           1        0      3                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris   male  22     1     0        A/5 21171
2           2        1      1 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer) female  38     1     0         PC 17599
3           3        1      3                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina female  26     0     0 STON/O2. 3101282
4           4        1      1        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel) female  35     1     0           113803
5           5        0      3                            Allen, Mr. William Henry   male  35     0     0           373450
6           6        0      3                                    Moran, Mr. James   male  NA     0     0           330877
```

Comment: Use `?is.na` for filtering NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example might help, by showing you how testing against `"NA"` (a valid character string) produces actual `NA` (missing) values, which stuffs up your selection of rows.

```
train <- data.frame(id=1:5, Age=c(1:3,NA,5))
train
#  id Age
#1  1   1
#2  2   2
#3  3   3
#4  4  NA
#5  5   5

train$Age=="NA"
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE

train[train$Age=="NA",]
#   id Age
#NA NA  NA

train$Age!="NA"
#TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA TRUE

train[train$Age!="NA",]
#   id Age
#1   1   1
#2   2   2
#3   3   3
#NA NA  NA
#5   5   5
```

You actually want to test using `is.na`:

```
is.na(train$Age)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

!is.na(train$Age)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

train[!is.na(train$Age),]
#  id Age
#1  1   1
#2  2   2
#3  3   3
#5  5   5
```

Comment: Thanks, It resolved my problem. Though I wounder why string `== "NA"` works but not `!= "NA"`?

Comment: @WoodChopper - it doesn't work. Comparing an `NA` vs `"NA"` gives an `NA`, which will just return a row full of `NA`s when you try to use it to select rows.

Comment: Okay, I got that finally :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is `"NA"` is a character, not the `NA` symbol. There's a function to test if some components of a vector are `NA`: `is.na`. You can see the difference with this example:

```
x = c("NA", NA)
x == NA
# [1] NA NA
x == "NA"
# [1] TRUE   NA
is.na(x)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

So, try:

```
train[!is.na(train$Age), ]
```

Comment: It should not work. See my new example. NA is not the same as "NA"